# Finding any one solution to two inequalities in 2 variables (Python)

Tags: sage, inequality

I have two inequalities as below and while I can find the appropriate regions for which the inequalities hold true, I am looking for any one particular value rather than solving the inequality by hand. So one of the solution in this case would be when d=-4.5 and g=3. And I want any one correct solution. I am using sage.

```
    Input: solve([-1/2*d + 1/2 < g, g < -d - 1],[d,g])
    Output: [[-2*g + 1 < d, d < -g - 1, 2 < g]]
```

The closest I have got is by using sympy modules but I was not able to solve 2 equations, only 1 works:

```
    Input: solve_univariate_inequality(x**2 >= 4, x, relational=False)
    Output:(−∞,−2]∪[2,∞)
```

Is anyone aware of a technique that would lead me to a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to why the Sage answer isn't acceptable.  It says any `g>2` so pick `g=4`, maybe, and then any `d` between `-2*g+1` and `-g-1`, so that would be between `-7` and `-5`, so `-6` works.  The point is to give you all answers.

You could do something like this, but you'd still have to look at the first solution to see what was appropriate for `d`, or find a way to programmatically extract that information - and that might be challenging, since in general your inequality may not have a nice solution like this, and the order of the inequalities in the solution might have a more random order.

```
var('d,g')
S = solve([-1/2*d + 1/2 < g, g < -d - 1],[d,g])[0]
[s.subs(g=4) for s in S]
```

I hope this at least helps you frame your question, if not perhaps even answer your actual query; good luck.

Comment: Solution from sage is acceptable. But I want one of the solutions (g=4,d=-6), not an inequality which I need to solve myself. Because there are many inqualities, I want to automate this process and one of solutions from these inequalities is being used in the other part of the program. Right now, I get inqualities and I solve them. Ideally, is there a way to tell sage to give me any one value for g and d which satisfies this inquality: -1/2*d + 1/2 < g, g < -d - 1. Thanks for the explanation above, it helped me get closer to the solution.